# Radio dial type functionality as seen on Where To? App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, user-interface

Straight forward question. I'm trying to understand UI design more and how to make it work with code. In particular there used to be an app that went through several design sessions, named Where To? by Tap Tap Tap. They had a table which they turned into a radio dial, screenshot:

[image: "Where To?" screen shot]
<sub>(source: [taptaptap.com](http://www.taptaptap.com/blog/media/the-easy-way-to-get-into-the-iphone-app-game/WhereToSmall.png))</sub>

My question is, is this nothing more than 22 or so images, with different states put together on top of a UIView? Each UIImageView is a button? How would something like this be put together? I'd love a tutorial on programmatically turning images into actual actions. If there's any book or blog which describes the process, that would be an ideal answer for me.

Any insight into how the above is done?

Answer (score 1):

I actually think it's a single image that has it's layer rotated in response to touch events and then calculates which is the active button based on the radial distance from the original position. It's not horribly complicated code (touchset change is left or right and rotate in response to that, modify the hittest method to respect the radial deltas) but the math is more than I can do before six cups of coffee.